# Android SwipeRefreshLayout NULL pointer exception SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener()

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to add pull to refresh functionality into listview.

**In fragment_page.xml (here is defined global listview)**

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/AppTheme.BaseActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xx.view.fragment.PageFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        style="@style/AppTheme.WrapContent.NoResult"
        android:text="@string/no_results"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And in Activity:**

```
public class MessageActivity extends TabBaseActivity implements ManageView, OnRefreshListener {

    private MessageController mMessageController;
    private int mSelectedTab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init();
        setUp(new String[]{"Unread", "Read", "Sent", "All"}, Constants.Adapter.MESSAGE_ADAPTER);
        mMessageController.loadMessages();

        //START  Swipe to refresh
        try {

            final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
            if(swipeContainer == null) {
                Logger.d("Null");
            }
            swipeContainer.setEnabled(false);
            swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
        //END  Swipe to refresh

    }
```

But swipeContainer is still null.

I tried to to it using the following tutorials:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

and

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html

But without the luck.

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

EDIT:

Content for view is set in init:

```
private void init() {
        mMessageController = MessageController.getInstance(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        mMessageController.setView(this);
        mSelectedTab = 0;
    }
```

Comment: did you set the content view? unless you did it inside of `init()` it is missing.

Comment: Yes, check my updated question please.

Comment: you need to call `setContentView()` before trying to find view elements

Comment: Cannot use setContentView() in TabBaseActivity

Comment: if you cannot use `setContentView`, you cannot use findViewById either

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your views in fragment (SwipeRefreshLayout, etc.), initialize your views in **onActivityCreated()** method. Once **onActivityCreated()** was called, you knew the activity was ready to be called upon.